# Using boolean simplification

Tags: logic-gates, boolean-algebra

Let's say we have this logic function:

g = abc + abc' + a'bc

and let's try to simplify this using laws

= ab(c+c') + a'bc

= ab + a'bc

and there's the point I stuck.

But using the good ol' Karnaugh map it seems that the result should be ab + bc

So, does absorption law apply here?

Or I got it all wrong from the start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you duplicate the first term:

g = abc + abc' + abc + a'bc

and reduce

g = ab(c+c') + (a+a')bc

you get

g = ab + bc

Comment: are you sure the first term was duplicated?  Looks like an additional term was added.

Comment: @TimSpriggs what do you suggest

Comment: @Tim It does not change the result if you add same value again in OR combination.

Comment: @TimSpriggs . using the identity  that  x = x+x  (if x is true then x OR x is true, if x is false then x OR x is false). By the same reasoning then it holds that abc = abc + abc

Comment: I guess I'm not as good at Boolean as you guys.  And that's no Boole.

Comment: @JImDearden abc = abc + abc makes no sense.  You can't assign the result of an expression on the right side to an expression on the left side, it must be a single variable on the left, unless your were trying to write some sort of equality which would be x = abc == abc + abc

Comment: Looks like someone is in my corner for once.  eh , Crosley?

Comment: why not g= b (a + c)?  That's what I got.  which looks to be the same.  lol

Comment: @TimSpriggs yes, you can factor out the b.

Comment: Yes.  ty, mr. croz

Comment: @tcrosley: c'mon, assignment uses `<=` or `:=`.  Except that we aren't talking about an HDL, but just algebraic notation, where indeed `=` does mean equality.

Comment: @BenVoigt except the other answers and comments have just been using a single = for assignment, e.g. g = ab + bc or g = b(a+c), so I was going by that.  But I get your point.